# How can I remove the current element in a foreach loop from the array, without changing the original array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

How can I get a new array with all elements except the current element passed into the foreach loop. See example below:

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
foreach($numbers as $numer){
    // Get a new array with 4 elements excluding the $numer
    // For example for first loop I want a array [2, 3, 4, 5]
}
```

I tried doing:

```
foreach($numbers as $i=>$numer) {
    unset($numbers[$i]);
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($numbers);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

It works but it alters original array. Is there any PHP function to get new array without affecting original one?

Comment: why negative rating??

Comment: [so] is not a code producing plattform. So if you want help, show us what you've already tried

Comment: would someone please tell me what's wrong with this question?

Comment: You don't show any research effort nor code of a solution that you've tried. You have a problem and want a solution, but you don't provide information about what you've tried to solve the problem on your own

Comment: OK I did. Would you please remove those negative ratings.

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Comment: @Rizier123 is it possible to make it work without using index? for example in a function where you don't have control on arguments passed, say update_array($arr, $item) { return /*Array excluding $item*/ }

Comment: @rkb updated my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31937312/3933332 to show how you can do it when you have the value.

Comment: @Rizier123 thanks :)

Comment: @rkb You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`array_diff_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php) to get the entire array, expect the current element, e.g.

```
<?php

    $numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    foreach($numbers as $key => $numer){
        print_r(array_diff_key($numbers, array_flip([$key])));
    }

?>
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't have the key, you can simply use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get all keys, e.g.

```
$numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$value = 32;
print_r(array_diff_key($numbers, array_flip(array_keys($numbers, $value))));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);   
if (($key = array_search($numer, $numbers)) !== false) {
   unset($numbers[$key]);
}
```

If you want to delete **all** instances of `$numer`, simply replace `if` with `while`.

Edit: I see you've changed your question to include not changing the original array. You can copy the array and manipulate the copied array in that case.

Comment: is it possible without using index? for example in a function where you don't have control on arguments passed, say `update_array($arr, $item) { return /*Array excluding $item*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
<?php
   $numbers = array(1,2,3);
    foreach($numbers as $index => $value){ 
        $temp = $numbers;
        unset($temp[$index]);
        $new_array = $temp;
        echo '<pre>'.print_r($new_array, true).'</pre>';
    }
?>
```